# image doesn't display in page while uploading to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

i got two issues while adding product .

1. while i try to upload the image into database , there is no image display after i click add product like show below.
   [image]
2. if i didn't attach the image and add to product , it should point to noimage pic, but it just create another product ID folder under /product_images/ path with no image. i have tried to install mkdirp version 0.5.1 also no luck. kindly help to suggest. below is my code.

Here is my route to post the product to the database:

```
   router.post('/add-product', function (req, res) {

    if (!req.files) { imageFile = ""; }
    if (req.files) {

        var imageFile = typeof (req.files.image) !== "undefined " ? req.files.image.name : "";
    }

    req.checkBody('title', 'Title must have a value.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('desc', 'Description must have a value.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('price', 'Price must have a value.').isDecimal();
    req.checkBody('image', 'You must upload an image').isImage(imageFile);

    var title = req.body.title;
    var slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var desc = req.body.desc;
    var price = req.body.price;
    var category = req.body.category;

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        Category.find(function (err, categories) {
            res.render('add_product', {
                errors: errors,
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                categories: categories,
                price: price
            });
        });
    } else {
        Product.findOne({ slug: slug }, function (err, product) {
            if (product) {
                req.flash('danger', 'Product title exists, choose another.');
                Category.find(function (err, categories) {
                    res.render('add_product', {
                        title: title,
                        desc: desc,
                        categories: categories,
                        price: price
                    });
                });
            } else {

                var price2 = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);

                var product = new Product({
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    desc: desc,
                    price: price2,
                    category: category,
                    image: imageFile
                });

                product.save(function (err) {
                    if (err)
                        return console.log(err);

                    mkdirp('public/product_images/' + product._id, function (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    });

                    mkdirp('public/product_images/' + product._id + '/gallery', function (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    });

                    mkdirp('public/product_images/' + product._id + '/gallery/thumbs', function (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    });

                    if (imageFile != "") {
                        var productImage = req.files.image;
                        var path = 'public/product_images/' + product._id + '/' + imageFile;

                        productImage.mv(path, function (err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                        });
                    }

                    req.flash('success', 'Product added!');
                    res.redirect('/admin/products');
                });
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Here is my product ejs file for display product added page

```
<%- include('_layouts/adminheader'); -%>

<h2 class="page-title">Products</h2>
<a href="/admin/products/add-product" class="btn btn-primary">Add a new product</a>
<br><br>

<% if (count > 0) { %>
<table class="table table-striped alignmiddle">
    <thead>
        <tr class="home">
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Product Image</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% products.forEach(function(product){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= product.title %></td>
            <td>$<%= parseFloat(product.price).toFixed(2) %></td>
            <td><%= product.category %></td>
            <td>
                <% if (product.image == "") { %>
                <img id="noimage" src="/images/noimage.png">
                <% } else {%>
                <img id="noimage" src="/product_images/<%= product._id %>/<%= product.image %>">
                <% }%>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/admin/products/edit-product/<%= product._id %>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a class="confirmDeletion" href="/admin/products/delete-product/<%= product._id %>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<% } else {%>
<h3 class="text-center">There are no products.</h3>
<% }%>

<%- include('_layouts/adminfooter'); -%>
```

This is the public folder setup for my app.js

```
// View Engine setup

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//// Set public folder
/*app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));*/
const static_path = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
app.use(express.static(static_path));
```

Here is my validation middleware:

```
customValidators:  {

     isImage: function(value, filename){
       var extension = (path.extname(filename)).toLowerCase();

       switch(extension){
        case '.jpg':
            return '.jpg';
        case '.jpeg':
            return '.jpeg'; 
        case '.png':
            return '.png'; 
        case '.':
            return 'jpg'; 

        default:
            return false; 
       }
     } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the urls you are supplying for the images, are they imported correctly . Also, If your files are actually less than 16 mb, please try using this Converter that changes the image of format jpeg / png to a format of saving to mongodb.
you can refer [here](https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter)
Please also mention the req body in the question.

Comment: i have tried to put install image coverter and put these two line in my app.js also. but it still cannot show the image app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '16mb', extended: true }));     // Make sure you add these two lines
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '16mb', extended: true }))    //Make sure you add these two lines

Comment: Is the url of img_src correct ?